# JUnit test case with Mockito throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I am writing a JUnit test case using Mockito and I am getting a NullPointerException.

**Business Code**

```java
public XRImage getImage(String imgId, List tagList) {
    _paramsMap.printContent();
    return _paramsMap.getImage(imgId, tagList);
}
```

**Test Code**

```java
@Test
public void getImageTest() {
    String imgId = new String("Test");
    List requiredTags = null;
    XRImage xRImage = Mockito.mock(XRImage.class);
    ImageParamsMap imageParamsMap = Mockito.mock(ImageParamsMap.class);
    imageParamsMap.addImage(imgId);
    when(imageParamsMap.getImage(imgId, requiredTags)).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(XRImage.class));
    XRImage getImage1 = acquisitionParamsManager.getImage(imgId, requiredTags);
    assertNotNull(getImage1);
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize your `acquisitionParamsManager`? You need to inject mock in this object

Comment: i did it using @InjectMocks

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
List requiredTags = null;
```

...

```
XRImage getImage1=acquisitionParamsManager.getImage(imgId,requiredTags);
```

You are passing in *null* for that List! Try an **empty** list instead.
And if that is a java.util.List; you are actually creating a **raw** generic type; and you should rather do something like `List<Whatever>` instead!

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the `imageParamsMap` mock object to be used instead of the `_paramsMap` instance variable?

If so, you will need to somehow set the `imageParamsMap` on `acquisitionParamsManager` before invoking the method. For example, assuming there was a setter available:

```
acquisitionParamsManager.setParamsMap(imageParamsMap);
XRImage getImage1 = acquisitionParamsManager.getImage(imgId, requiredTags);
```

Mock injection would be another option if no setter is available. Beyond that, it is hard to debug without additional code and/or line numbers where the exception was thrown.

---

Unrelated, but calling the `addImage()` in your test case does not actually accomplish anything. If you want to verify that this method gets called, then try adding this statement after your assert:

```
verify(imageParamsMap).addImage(imgId);
```